# Split String with Random Length using DOS/Batch

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, split

I have a log file I need to process and extract data from.  Each line contains a string of an event log output.  Unfortunately, the parts of the string is NOT uniformly formatted.  Here are a few example lines:

```
"Some random length string.  0x8dda46 0x1 0x384 C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo0.exe  "
"Some random leeeength string.  0xa95ac2 0x8cc C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo1.exe %%1936 0xcc0  "
"Some random leength string.  0xbcd668 0x330 C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo2.exe %%1936 0xf38  "
"Some random leeeeeeeength string.  0xbcd668 0x1 0x330 C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo2.exe  "
"Some random leeength string.  0x352c44 0xfc0 C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo3.exe %%1936 0x92c  "
"Some random leeeeength string.  0xa95ac2 0x0 0x8cc C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo1.exe  "
"Some random leength string.  0x352c44 0x0 0xfc0 C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path\foo3.exe  "
```

I need to extract the "foo.exe" file name without the full path and the HEX value just before the "C:\Progra..." (it's the process ID)

so I want the output be:

```
0x384 foo0.exe
0x8cc foo1.exe
0x330 foo2.exe
0x330 foo2.exe
0xfc0 foo3.exe
0x8cc foo1.exe
0xfc0 foo3.exe
```

I'm trying to achieve the goal with as less "hard coded" search/replace as possible since many parts of the string is not going to be the same content or same length.  I tried to use FOR /F to split the string, but I have no way to locate the two columns as they are always changing.  Only thing is constant is the "C:\Program Files (x86)" part. (Plus FOR has a 52 variable limit)

I have written some tricky batch files, but I'm starting to think I'm asking too much of DOS ;-)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a task that calls for regular expressions, and for regular expressions at the windows command-line you want powershell. Fortunately, you can run powershell from a batch file or the DOS command-prompt:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content 'c:\full_path_here\input.log') -replace '.+?(0x[0-9a-f]{3}) .+?\\([^\\]+\.exe).*', '$1 $2'"
```

This has a few parts

1. `powershell -Command` runs the entire expression in quotation marks as though it were run from the powershell command line
2. `Get-Content` is like the linux `cat` command - it reads the entirety of the file contents
3. `-replace` uses regular expressions to replace the content on each line of the file with the two matched expressions in parentheses

Comment: A string like "0x123 " within the path causes your command to give the wrong result.

Comment: @dbenham, is that from visual inspection or testing? I think it will work but it likely won't be a problem for OP anyway. If it were, then a more specific regular expression can be used.

Comment: I tested. Also, You want your initial `.+` to be greedy, otherwise the expression could match text from the initial random text.

Comment: This is very clean to use.  Didn't know you can call PowerShell like that.  I resisted using PowerShell since 1) still old-school DOS person and do not want to learn PS extensively (probably should), 2) then have to write the whole thing in PowerShell.

This is great! I can just call it when I needed (like using regex) and still in my DOS-comfort-zone.

Since this whole thing is a subroutine of a bigger process, I modified the regex slightly and its working great!

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%a IN (q28333414.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%c IN ("%%~b") DO CALL :process %%c&CALL :report "%%d

)
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET hexval=%~3
IF DEFINED hexval shift&GOTO process
SET "hexval=%~1"
SET "drive=%~2:"

GOTO :eof

:report
SET "line=%drive%%~1"
SET "line="%line:.exe=.exe"%"
FOR %%r IN (%line%) DO ECHO %hexval% %%~nxr&GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q28333414.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The first process simply throws away each (space-delimited) parameter between the `.` and `:` until there are exactly two left - the required `hexval` and the drive letter.

The `report` process re-attaches the drive letter and encloses it and the `.exe` name in quotes. the `for  %%r` picks the first string, shucks off the quotes, spits out the result and all's done.

---

Edit : fixed report to show name and extension of file only as required and dbenham comment

---

Breaking news: (literally!)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q28333414.txt) DO SET "line=%%~a"&CALL :process "!line::=" "!"
)
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "hexval=%~3"
IF DEFINED hexval shift&GOTO process
CALL :lastbar1 %%~1
SET "filename=%~2"
SET filename="c:%filename:.exe =.exe" %
FOR %%r IN (%filename%) DO ECHO %hexval% %%~nxr&GOTO :eof
GOTO :eof

:lastbar1
SET "hexval=%~3"
IF DEFINED hexval shift&GOTO lastbar1
SET "hexval=%~1"
GOTO :eof
```

OK - let's try this, then.

For each line, replace all evil colons with `" "` and pass resultant quoted-string sequence to a subroutine.

Shift the parameters until there are but 2, which will be the string before and after the final countdown - er, colon.

Repeat the process for the first parameter. The penultimate value is the required hexval.

with the second parameter, add `"c:` before and `"` after any `.exe`, so the result is a quoted full-filename and dross; spit out the `hexval` and filename and done...

small revision in the rather dim light of the "`&`" comment - the famous `set "var=whatever"` formula fails with `&` included in this case (as in subdirectory "Documents & Settings") so the enclosing quotes can be removed as trailing spaces are not relevant. Would have been useful to know what the test data triggering the problem was though - reduces guesswork.

Comment: Clever, but your output includes the full path. The OP wants just the exe name without the path. You just need to ECHO `%%~nxr` instead of `%%~r`

Comment: Sorry didn't say this in my post, some of the "random string" does have `:` and multiple `.` so that they will break your script.

Comment: @JMouse888 - I don't think that is true, did you try Magoo's script with your data? I've run some tests, and it appears to me that it always grabs the latest values from the line. The only thing that could break it is if `:` and `.` occur after the desired `.exe`.

Comment: @dbenham : er, if the "random string" contains more than one `.` then the original will grab the string before a `:` occurring between the first `.` and the second. If `:` is unique in any line, then you're right - and it would appear that `%%a` is irrelevant; `for/f "delims=" %%b in (file)` would work, it appears.

Comment: Yeah, I had done a simple test, and your original code seemed to work. But I added even more `:` and `.` and did manage to break your original. Your new code appears to fix the problem.

Comment: @Magoo the latest code just gave "**& was unexpected at this time**" error.

Comment: @Magoo - I opt to use the one-liner PowerShell solution from @NextInLine since this post is actually a subroutine of a bigger process (a few `for /f` is around this subroutine so I need the cleanness of the PS solution.  I also did not select this as the answer since it's still a little buggy.  However, this is fine piece of batch scripting (by shifting the string with a subroutine call).  I'm definitely keeping this in my vault for future use.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Any good regex utility you can lay your hands on should be able to solve your problem. I like to use my [JREPL.BAT hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855). It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Assuming your file is test.log, then I would use:

```
jrepl ".* (0x[0-9A-F]+) C:\\Program Files \(x86\)\\(?:.*\\)?([^\\]+\.exe) .*" "$1 $2" /i /f test.log
```

On each line it looks for the last occurrence of a hex string sandwiched by spaces that precedes a file path that begins with "C:\Program Files (x86)\" and ends with ".exe". I made the search ignore case.

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes that there are not backslashes into the random string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=\" %%a in (logFile.txt) do (
   rem Extract the HEX value
   for %%A in (%%~a) do (
      set "value=!lastButOne!"
      set "lastButOne=%%A"
   )
   rem Extract the file name
   for /F %%A in ("%%e") do set "name=%%A"
   echo !value! !name!
)
```

Comment: Won't work in the general case; only if the executable is at exactly 3 directories deep and even then, not if the executable name contains space...

Comment: This has the honor of being the fastest solution offered thusfar, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hybrid batch + JScript script (but still a .bat file) that will perform a regexp replace similar to NextInLine's PowerShell solution.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "logfile=test.log"

rem // Ask JScript to parse log.  On each line, %%I = hex.  %%J = exe.
for /f "tokens=1*" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%logfile%"') do (
    echo %%I %%J
)

rem // End main runtime.
goto :EOF

@end
// JScript chimera portion
var fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    log = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1);

while (!log.AtEndOfStream) {
    var line = log.ReadLine();
    WSH.Echo(line.replace(/^.+(0x[0-9a-f]+) \w:\\.+?\\(\w+\.exe).+$/i, "$1 $2"));
}

log.Close();
```

Course if I were in your boat I'd probably use GnuWin32 `sed`.

```
sed -r -e "s/^.*(0x[a-f0-9]+) \w:.+\\(.+\.exe).*$/\1 \2/i" test.log
```

---

Just for giggles, I ran some time tests of each fully-working solution against the O.P.'s test log file above, running each several times and getting the mode duration (the result occurring most often).

- Aacini's solution: 0.013s (Excellent, but depends on narrow matches)
- `sed`: 0.015s (simplest)
- Magoo's solution: 0.034s (clever!)
- my JScript hybrid: 0.034s (the best, of course)
- dbenham's `jrepl.bat`: 0.051s (powerful Swiss army knife solution)
- NextInLine's PowerShell: hanged my timer script, but felt like about a half a second after the initial painful priming of PowerShell

Comment: I have no idea. But your regex does have a flaw - it can give the wrong result if  a hex string is embedded within the path.

Comment: @dbenham Very well.  I changed the regexp in the batch script to prevent that.